# aws sam - do something when last item in the queue was processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

I have question about sqs queues. Is there a way to detect/catch some event when last item in the queue is being processed and do something after that? If not do you have any indea how could I achieve that?

Lets assume I send to queue 300 items (in 5 chunks). After last item I want to do something (send an email or display some notification). Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in AWS that will send you a message when a queue has been emptied, but you could add a check to see how many messages are in the queue after each batch of work is done & send an email based on that. Eg. after batch 1, there are 295 items left in the queue -> don't send; after batch 60 there are zero items left in the queue -> send the email.

Comment: yeah but when sending 300 requests to queue it takes around 1-2 minutes to do that so after last batch is being sent (from my app) sqs is still processing the queue

Comment: I'm not understanding your concern about 1-2 minutes to submit 300 requests. SQS is a way of separating job creation from processing so they can each proceed at their own pace. Say it takes 1-2 minutes to submit 300 requests and 10-15 minutes to process those requests -- according to your original question, it sounds like you want to be notified when the queue is empty, ie. after 10-15 minutes of processing. If that's not what you're asking, you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: yes thats is exactly what im asking. I want to be notified after 15 minutes (when the queue is empty) but there is one thing. Same queue can be used by lets say. Mr A and Mr B. If Mr B queues something then only Mr B needs to be notified because mr a and mr b can queue something to the same sqs at the same time, right?